# Collection for fast read in C#

Tags: c#

I am looking for a collection class for the scenario below:

- Fast collection lookup, one item at a time.
- The collection contains around 300 K items.
- Collection population speed might not be important, but ideally fast too.
- No update/delete/insert is needed once collection is loaded

Example of items of type `Ip2Location` that would be populated into the collection:

```
public class Ip2Location
{
   public long IpFrom {get; set;}
   public long IpTo {get; set;}
   public string Country {get; set;}  
}

IpFrom      IpTo        Country
16909056    16909311    AU
16909312    16941055    US
```

Item lookup against the collection is done via a specified IP, like this:

```
IpFrom < currentIp < IpTo
```

Any ideas, including reference links, would be very much appreciated!

Comparison: `HashSet, SortedSet`

Are there any better collection classes?

Reference: the comparison table in the link below:
http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/06/16/c.net-fundamentals-choosing-the-right-collection-class.aspx

**Update**:

Problem using Array.BinarySearch:

```
var index = Array.BinarySearch(ipCountries, new IpCountry { IpFrom = 16909056}, new Ip2LocationComparer());
```

It works in small numbers of row, doesn't work in 300k items (e.g. index is -(totalrow+1) ). The search item is loaded within the 300 K items collection.

```
        public class Ip2LocationComparer: IComparer<IpCountry>
        {
            public int Compare(IpCountry x, IpCountry y)
            {
                if (x != null && y != null)
                    return (x.IpFrom <= y.IpFrom && y.IpFrom <= x.IpTo)? 0 : -1;

                return -1;

            }
        }
```

**Update 2**

I changed it to below

```
public class Ip2LocationComparer: IComparer<IpCountry>
            {
                public int Compare(IpCountry x, IpCountry y)
                {
       if (x != null && y != null)

            {
                if (x.IpFrom > y.IpFrom)
                    return 1;

                if (x.IpFrom < y.IpFrom)
                    return -1;

                if (x.IpFrom == y.IpFrom)
                {
                    if (y.IpFrom > x.IpTo)
                        return 1;

                    if (y.IpFrom < x.IpTo)
                        return -1;

                }

            }

            return 0;
}
```

But the index return from BinarySearch is still nagtive, which is right between the matching item and the follow item. e.g. if my search IpFrom is 3, the index is between 2 and 4. Why it doen't return 2? I haven't test the IpTo scenario yet.

Any idea would be appreciated!

Comment: Your search method isn't working because your comparer is...broken.  You need to return -1 if x is "before" y, 0 if x and y are the same, and 1 if y comes "after" x.  In your case you almost certainly want the implementation to be `x.IpFrom.CompareTo(y.IpFrom) and then return the `IpTo` comparison if the result is zero (also with a null check).  That will give you the first item in range.  Then keep going until you hit an item in which the `to` range is before the current item and you're done.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I posted update 2. Please have a look, any idea would be very much appreicated!

Comment: Your comparer is now clearly working.  You could do it with less code, but there's nothing wrong with what you have.  BinarySearch is designed to return a negative value; just look at the documentation for the method and the examples on MSDN to see it's proper usage.

Comment: Thanks! The comparer in Update 1 works for testing case with small numbers of rows, but doesn't work for 300 K items. Any idea?

Comment: The first comparer is just completely broken.  If it works it was pure luck because the set was so small.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could store this in an array.

If you sorted the array after populating, then a [BinarySearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cy9f6wb.aspx) would be a very fast way to lookup where your `currentIp` falls.

Comment: Thanks! What about HashSet, and SortedSet? And you mean sort it by IpFrom? Because IpFrom is unique.

Comment: No, you want an array and a binary search for what you are doing. A hashset or sorted list have to do look ups and even if you can iterate over them, there is no way they will be as performant as a Binary Search.

Comment: @Pingpong a plain array sorted by IpFrom would work with a binary search on IpFrom

Comment: Thank you! I will test it, and post the result.

Comment: I have problem getting the lookup item using BinarySearch. I posted my finding under Update section. Could you please have a look?

Comment: @Pingpong - Just compare off the first item.  BinarySearch will return a negative number if you're between two values and you can use ~result to figure out where in the list you fall. See the help and sample for details.

Answer (score 0):

Data-structure wise, you could try a dictionary or sorted list, although with 300000 items, you may experience problems. I'd be curious to hear the result, though. A plain array with BinarySearch might not be a bad option, either.

You might also consider harnessing all the cores on the machine for quick lookup. You can use [.AsParallel() extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asparallel.aspx) on most colllections, which will prep the collection for querying on multiple cores.